# Select the name of a buyer with the highest sum of orders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

1. Buyers:

[image]

2. Orders:

[image]

I want to get the name of a buyer with the highest amount of orders (in this case it would be buyer C with id 3).

I wrote the following query:

```
select top 1 b.Name, sum (o.Amount) as amt from Buyers b
join Orders o on o.BuyerId = b.Id
group by Name
order by amt desc
```

It gives me Name and amt in resulting row.

[image]

How to exclude *amt* from the result and display **only** *Name* of the buyer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `sum (o.Amount) as amt`  from select and add `sum (o.Amount)  desc` in order by

```
select top 1 b.Name from Buyers b
join Orders o on o.BuyerId = b.Id
group by Name
order by sum (o.Amount)  desc
```

Comment: So obvious, I almost feel embarrassed. Thanks!